# Create direct links from URLs to files on Google Drive in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, concatenation

I want to create direct links to my files on Google Drive that I have in Google Sheets. I know how to do this manually but need a formula to extract the unique ID of one URL and add it to an other.

I tried to do this using =HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE and REGEXREPLACE(ImportXML but I really got nowhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put these scripts into your script editor.  Run the onOpen once it will create a menu with one item.  Now go back to your spreadsheet and make sure that there is a blank column to the right of your list of filenames and then select all of your filenames and the cells to the right of them.  And then from the My Tools menu select "Get Links to Files". It will put the file id's next to all of the selected files.  It's been running slowly today so be patient.  Also if one of the files causes an error I have no error recovery so you'll have to do that one by hand.  I wouldn't select too many at one time because there is a 6 minute script timeout.

```
function onOpen()
{
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('My Tools')
    .addItem('Get Links to Files','testFind')
    .addToUi();
}

function testFind()
{
  var sht = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rng = sht.getActiveRange();
  var rngA = rng.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<rngA.length;i++)
  {
    rngA[i][1]=findFileByNameReturnId(rngA[i][0]);
  }
  rng.setValues(rngA);
}

function findFileByNameReturnId(name)
{
 var rv = '';
 var files = DriveApp.getFiles();
 while (files.hasNext()) 
 {
   var file = files.next();
   if(file.getName()==name)
   {
     rv = file.getId();
   }
 }
```

Comment: i already have the list of files in a sheet, just need to extract the ID from it so i can add it to the other one. I have no idea how to use/implement  google scripts but thanks any way.

Comment: I copied this into your script editor and ran the onOpen for you so now you have a MyTools menu.  Bring in the files names in column A and select some of column A and some of column B and choose GetLinksToFiles.  And if this works  out please check off my answer